# Image segmentation algorithm in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I need to implement an image segmentation function in MATLAB based on the principles of the connected components algorithm, but with a few modifications. This is intended for very simple, 2D images, with a background color and some objects in different colors.

The idea is that, taking the image as a matrix, I provide a tool to select the background color (it will vary for every image). Then, when the value of the color of the background of the image is selected, I have to segment all the objects in the image, and the result should be a labeled matrix, of the same size of the image, with 0's for the background, and a different number for each object.

This is a graphic example of what I mean:

[image]

I understand the idea of how to do it, but I do not know how to implement it on MATLAB. For each pixel (matrix position) I should mark it as visited and then if the value corresponds to the one of the background, assign 0, if not, assign another value. The objects can be formed by different colors, so in the end, I need to segment groups of adjacent pixels, whatever their color is. Also I have to use 8-connectivity, in order to count the green object of the example image as only one object and not 4 different ones. And also, the objects should be counted from top to bottom, and from left to right.

Is there a simple way of doing this in MATLAB? I know the `bwlabel` function, but it works for binary images only, so I'd like to adapt it to my case.

Comment: Have you seen the Matlab tutorials on image segmentation, http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/image-segmentation.html, specifically I think the Otsu method will help you, more specifically look at the `bwconncomp` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you know the background color, you can easily convert your image into a binary mask of the same size:

```
bw=img!=bg_color;
```

Once you have a binary mask you can call `bwlavel` with 8-connectivity argument as you suggested yourself.

Note: you might want to convert your color image from RGB representation to an indexed image using `rgb2ind` before processing.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post the whole MATLAB implementation? Thank you!